# boolean (Boolean) - getter is vs get

Tags: java, wsimport

It looks like everyone says that right getter for:

- primitive boolean -> getter *is*
- object Boolean -> getter *get*

Example:

```java
public class Test {

    private boolean primitive;
    private Boolean object;

    public boolean isPrimitive() {
         return primitive;
    }
    public Boolean getObject() {
        return object;
    }
    //..
}
```

**Question:**

Is there any spec or document that states this is correct and this is the way to specify getters for boolean values? Or this is only a common assumption?

I'm asking becouse for example *wsimport* generates getter *is* for Boolean object. Is this a tool bug, or this is allowed and correct?

In the other hand some framweorks don't work properly with such getters. For example JSF (EL) or Dozer.

Comment: The rudest name for a reference variable is `object`

Comment: `is` in my opinion only works if the boolean name is an adjective and not a noun.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Lots of libs would disagree. Usually when dealing with abstract/super types ... Gson, for example ... `JsonElement.isJsonArray()`

Comment: I sometimes use `has` when `is` doesn't really sound right XD

Comment: @user1600770: me too. But only in places where nothing expects the class to follow bean specifications.

Comment: upvoted because I stumbled upon this problem while using dozer (mapping framework expects "get..." for Boolean Object)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The getter method for the field `boolean myField` is `getMyfield()` or `isMyField()` (it's up to the user to choose). I personally use the second format, as many source code generating tools do.

This format is a standard, it is defined in the `JavaBeans` specification. See the **section 8.3.2** of this documentation:
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/

Quote from the docs:

> ```
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
>   public boolean is<PropertyName>();
> ```

The documentation doesn't talk about the primitive wrappers like the `Boolean` class.

Comment: ... let alone that the spec doesn't even mention boolean attributes ;)

Answer (score 10):

```java
// "is" used because the value can be either true or false. It's like asking isTrue?
public boolean isPrimitive() {
     return primitive;
}

// "get" is used because the value returned can be either true, false or null.  
// So, the third state 'null' makes you wonder if 'is' should be used or 'get'.
// "get" is more appropriate as Boolean can also have null.
public Boolean getObject() {
    return object;
}
```

But frankly, it's left to the developer. There's nothing "wrong" in using `getBoolean()` on a boolean value (`is` makes more sense, that's it).

Comment: We are you not choosen as the correct answer, I can only wonder
By the way lombok have the same reasoning as you